# C++ order of element initialization in aggregate class

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initialization

I know, that in aggregate class

> Each array element or non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition, is copy-initialized from the corresponding clause of the initializer list.

But my question is: can we use previous initialized elements in initialization?
Like:

```
std::array<int, 2> d = { 3, d[0] };
```

or

```
int d[] = {3, d[0]};
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't _think_ so, but... I don't know

Comment: It seems to work on both Visual Studio and gcc. I wouldn't recommend it though.

Comment: There's probably a difference between objects with trivial and non-trivial initialization, see [basic.life] and [class.cdtor].

Comment: This is http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1343 (see the last note)